# R: Put vectors into bins, then find the average of those bins

Tags: r

Let's say I have the two following vectors

```
zones1 <- c(1:1491)
luminosity1 <- seq(0,3.0734451332212645E-046,length.out=1491)
```

I would like to place the data into 500 bins (or better yet, n bins, where n is any whole number), then eventually get 500 length vectors of `zones1`,`luminosity1`, with each one the 500 elements in such vectors being the average value of the bin. Is there a convenient way to do this in R?

Comment: `cut(zones1, 500)` should put the data into `500` bins.

Comment: and `aggregate(zones1 ~ bin,cbind(zones1,bin = cut(zones1, 500)), FUN = "mean")` calculates the average per bin.

Comment: `tapply(luminosity1, cut(luminosity1, 50), mean)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df <- tibble(zones1=zones1,luminosity1=luminosity1) %>%
  mutate(bins = cut(zones1, breaks=500)) %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  summarize(mean_zones1 = mean(zones1),
            mean_luminosity1 = mean(luminosity1))

mean_zones1 <- pull(df, mean_zones1)
mean_luminosity1 <- pull(df, mean_luminosity1)
```

The means will depend on if you want to bin zone1 or luminosity1. Here I did zones1 but you can swap it into luminosity1 if thats what you want instead (it wasnt clear in your question)

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "means". I want to bin luminosity1

Comment: means = averages. In your specific case it shouldn't matter which one you use to bin as both your zones1 and luminosity1 vectors are linear. however if one of the vectors are not linear you will see a difference in averages depending on which vector you end up binning. So use the vector you want to bin in the cut function and all should be fine!